# Red Hat Enterprise Linux Qt 4.7.0 install error

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, qt4

I'm running a virtual machine, using VMWare Player, running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 6.4 x86_64 and I'm trying to install Qt 4.7.0 from the qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0.tar.gz file on Qt's download site. Running the ./configure command works normally, but when running gmake, I encounter the following errors:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `libQtCore.so': Operation not supported
gmake[1]: [../../lib/libQtCore.so.4.7.0] Error 1 (ignored)
ln -s libQtCore.so.4.7.0 libQtCore.so.4
ln: creating symbolic link `libQtCore.so.4': Operation not supported
gmake[1]: [../../lib/libQtCore.so.4.7.0] Error 1 (ignored)
ln -s libQtCore.so.4.7.0 libQtCore.so.4.7
ln: creating symbolic link `libQtCore.so.4.7': Operation not supported
gmake[1]: [../../lib/libQtCore.so.4.7.0] Error 1 (ignored)
```

gmake works normally for a while

```
.obj/release-shared/qdom.o: In function `QList<QDomNodePrivate*>::detach_helper(int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:693: undefined reference to `QListData::detach(int)'
.obj/release-shared/qdom.o: In function `QList<QDomNodePrivate*>::detach_helper_grow(int, int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:663: undefined reference to `QListData::detach_grow(int*, int)'
.obj/release-shared/qxml.o: In function `QList<QString>::detach_helper(int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:693: undefined reference to `QListData::detach(int)'
.obj/release-shared/qxml.o: In function `QList<QString>::detach_helper_grow(int, int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:663: undefined reference to `QListData::detach_grow(int*, int)'
.obj/release-shared/qxml.o: In function `QList<QXmlAttributes::Attribute>::detach_helper(int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:693: undefined reference to `QListData::detach(int)'
.obj/release-shared/qxml.o: In function `QList<QXmlAttributes::Attribute>::detach_helper_grow(int, int)':
/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h:663: undefined reference to `QListData::detach_grow(int*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [../../lib/libQtXml.so.4.7.0] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/user/CBrown/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/xml'
gmake: *** [sub-xml-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Internet access is not allowed on this machine.

Comment: what user are you doing this as, what are the mount options on /mnt/user/CBrown, and what's the underlying file-system?

Comment: We're running this as root. The underlying file system is Common Internet File System (cifs). The mount options are rw, relatim.

Comment: There's your problem.  Copy the source locally, or to a file-system that understands symlinks.